# How to kill celery worker process for process restart

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, celery, python-multiprocessing

I have a celery worker process that creates one socket to an external server in `celery.signals.worker_process_init`. If the connection can't be established and an exception is raised the celery worker fails to start, which is the intended behaviour.

That socket class also sends occasional heartbeat packets using a `threading.Timer`. Unfortunately, because the Timer thread has no special exception handling, my worker doesn't quit if something happens to the connection.

I started catching exceptions from my socket read and write operations and have tried a bunch of things to gracefully stop the current worker process:

```
sys.exit(1)  # Doesn't kill the worker process (because it's running in a thread?)
```

next attempt, I saw it mentioned somewhere in `celery/billiard` issues:

```
raise SystemExit("Socket error")  # Same, I guess
```

this works:

```
os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGHUP)
```

BUT the celery worker supervisor process goes into a fast spin creating celery worker processes that exit immediately, instead of giving up and dying after a few attempts.

Is there a nicer way to signal the death of a celery worker process from outside a celery task?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. I ended up creating a separate script to manage workers.

Create an infinite while loop, sleep for required time and then create/kill worker process.

```
while True:
    time.sleep(5)
    # create workers if possible
    # kill stale workers if not required.
```